# Chain two server call in one NgEffects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx and I don't know how to chain two server call in one ngEffect. Have you any idea how to do it please I need your help.

```
      @Effect() patternsSources$ :Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(GET_PATTERN_SOURCE_ACTION)
    .switchMap(action => this.service.getPatternSource(action.payload))
    .map((patternsData:Sources) =>  new GetPatternsSourcesResponse(patternsData))


  @Effect() patternsList$ :Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(GET_PATTERN_LIST_ACTION)
    .switchMap(action => this.service.getPatternList(action.payload))
    .map((data) => new GetPatternsListResponse(data));
```

In this behaviour the first call is interrupeted and only the second call is processed

**EDIT**

The reducer function

```
export function storeData(state:UiStoreData=INITIAL_STORE_DATA, action:Action) : UiStoreData {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_PATTERN_SOURCE_RESPONSE_ACTION :
      return handleGetPatternSourcesResponse(state,action as GetPatternsSourcesResponse);
    case GET_PATTERN_LIST_RESPONSE_ACTION:
      return handleGetPatternListResponse(state,action as GetPatternsListResponse);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and the dispatch action

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public store:Store<ApplicationState>) {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetPatternsSourcesAction('/sources'));
    this.store.dispatch(new GetPatternsListAction('/rules'));

  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
export class GetPatternsSourcesAction implements Action {
  type = GET_PATTERN_SOURCE_ACTION
  constructor(public payload?:string) {}
}

export class GetPatternsSourcesResponse implements Action {
  type = GET_PATTERN_SOURCE_RESPONSE_ACTION;
  constructor(public payload?:Sources) {}
}

export class GetPatternsListAction implements Action {
  type: string = GET_PATTERN_LIST_ACTION;
  constructor(public payload?:string) {}
}

export class GetPatternsListResponse implements Action {
  type: string = GET_PATTERN_LIST_RESPONSE_ACTION;
  constructor(public payload?:PatternList) {}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to chain them ? They look as two separate actions to me and each should have it's own effect. The code should work fine as it is.

Comment: beacause I use one reducer and i lose the first call data, I don't know. What I have in the reducer is only the first data

Comment: Even if you have one reducer you have two actions also (GetPatternsSourcesResponse and GetPatternsListResponseAction). They should have a different type and handle in the reducer each case.

Comment: Maybe update the question with the definition of the actions and the reducer so it's more clear.

Comment: done. I add the dispatched action and the reducer function

Comment: That looks ok, you should check that the type is different in the actions (not the same constant) and that the handleGet... methods are working correctly.

Comment: I add the actions. I think the problem is in switchMap operator

Comment: If I dispatch one action I get the correct data but if I combine two actions I get only the last one !

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't sound like a dispatching problem.

seems like your methods:

```
handleGetPatternSourcesResponse(state,action as GetPatternsSourcesResponse);
```

and

```
handleGetPatternListResponse(state,action as GetPatternsListResponse);
```

operate on the same part of the state. i see no other way for a sentence 'i get the same data in reducer' make sense.
so, you should have 2 different places in the state: patternslist and patternSources and each complete action should handle then accordingly in reducer.
that way you can later do store.select(partYouNeed).

Comment: There is no way to chain two server call?

Comment: there sure is: Observable.zip(request1ObservableResolved, request2ObservableResolved, (first, second) => first && second). where request1ObservableResolved and request2ObservableResolved are booleans saying that your requests are done (which comes from flag from the store).